# Mandrill - Merge Vals Null Value

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I have merge vals working correctly in Mandrill when dynamic text is sent in.

I am trying to do something where if the dynamic content is null, don't show anything.

```
*|IF:BUY!=null|* 
    *|BUY|*
*|END:IF|*
```

When I do this *|BUY|* appears when BUY is null.

Is there anyway in Mandrill to do conditional merge tags for empty dynamic content?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem, but if you're just wanting to conditionally display a string... couldn't you set BUY to either the string your want or an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should let Mandrill evaluate the variable:

```
*|IF:BUY|* 
    *|BUY|*
*|END:IF|*
```

This will only show the variable's contents when it's not empty (so not null and not an empty string). This does not match exactly what you asked but may be what you intended to do.